# Jar mismatch when importing ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to create an ActionBarSherlock project, I've downloaded the library and connected it to my project. In Problems window I see the following message: Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Actionbarsherlock has the support library in it. This probably causes a conflict if the support library is also in your main project. Renaming the support library should fix this.

That is if the support library is causing the mismatch.

Comment: Removing support library from my project's libs directory has solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

a simple right click on the ActionBarSherlock library project then

Android Tools -> Add Support Library

A dialog will be opened, accept the license and click install.

Eclipse ADT will download the right support library for you.

Comment: This worked for me with ActionBarSherlock version 4.2.0 but when I switched to version 4.3.1 I had to manually delete the android-support-v4 !

Comment: I've spent hours on this. Already did this manually, but ofcourse Eclipse couldn't accept it. THIS however worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The above solution did not work for me .However , I deleted the supported library in libs folder of ActionBarSherlock and manually copied the android-support-v4 jar file from android-sdk/extras/support/v-4 to the same . I then followed the usual steps . It worked !

Answer (score 0):

I can fix this:

1. Right click your Project Properties
2. Click Java Build Path
3. Remove the android-support-v4 jar you see in the "root"
4. Right click on "Android tools" -> Fix project...