# Couple of android-support-v4, how do I remove them?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, pull-to-refresh

I am pretty new to Android

I am using 2 libraries in my project:

1. ActionBarSherlock - http://actionbarsherlock.com/
2. Pull-to-refresh - https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

After a succesful of use with ActionBarSherlock and succesful import (using the android-support-v4.jar that comes bundled with it), I wanted to add Pull-to-Refresh to my project..
I then went to my project properties to add the pull-to-refresh library, but encountered a problem - "Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies." I tried different approches to try to fix the problem like removing the android-support-v4 from the ActionBarSherlock and pull-to-refresh libraries and re-add them to my project properties + adding the android-support-v4 from the extras folder of the ADT..

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: remove one of them from the libs folder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405659/jar-mismatch-when-importing-actionbarsherlock

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing something wrong?

Sort of.

The requirements in your case are:

1. Each Android project needs to have access the JAR, either directly or by depending upon an Android library project that has the JAR, and
2. The JAR has to be the *same* JAR for any given JAR filename (same size, same MD5 hash)

The simplest solution for your scenario is to copy the latest JAR into *both* library projects, and not have the JAR in your main application project.

Comment: I have tried to remove the android-support-v4 from both of the libraries of ActionBarSherlock & Pull-to-refresh and remove it from main application - nothing seems to work, I am now trying another pull-to-refresh library - https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh

Comment: @dinbrca: "I have tried to remove the android-support-v4 from both of the libraries of ActionBarSherlock & Pull-to-refresh" -- that is not what my answer tells you to do.